# Does metal have a back buffer?

Tags: ios, metal

I'm currently tracking down some visual popping in my Metal app, and believe it is because I'm drawing directly to framebuffer, not a back-buffer

```
  // this is when I've finished passing commands to the render buffer and issue the draw command.  I believe this sends all the images directly to the framebuffer instead of using a backbuffer
  [renderEncoder endEncoding];
  [mtlCommandBuffer presentDrawable:frameDrawable];
  [mtlCommandBuffer commit];
  [mtlCommandBuffer release];
  //[frameDrawable present];   // This line isn't needed (and I believe is performed by presentDrawable
```

Several googles later, I haven't found any documentation of back-buffers in metal.  I know I could roll my own, but I can't believe metal doesn't support a back buffer.

Here is the code snippet of how I've setup my CAMetalLayer object.

```
+ (id)layerClass
{
    return [CAMetalLayer class];
}

- (void)initCommon
{
    self.opaque          = YES;
    self.backgroundColor = nil;
    ...
}

-(id <CAMetalDrawable>)getMetalLayer
{
    id <CAMetalDrawable> frameDrawable;
    while (!frameDrawable && !frameDrawable.texture)
    {
        frameDrawable = [self->_metalLayer nextDrawable];
    }
    return frameDrawable;
}
```

Can I enable a backbuffer on my CAMetalLayer object, or will I need to roll my own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume by *back-buffer*, you mean a renderbuffer that is being rendered to, while the corresponding *front-buffer* is being displayed?

In Metal, the concept is provided by the drawables that you extract from `CAMetalLayer`. The `CAMetalLayer` instance maintains a small pool of drawables (generally 3), retrieves one of them from the pool each time you invoke `nextDrawable`, and returns it back to the pool after you've invoked `presentDrawable` and once rendering is complete (which may be some time later, since the GPU runs asynchronously from the CPU).

Effectively, on each frame loop, you grab a *back-buffer* by invoking `nextDrawable`, and make it eligible to become the *front-buffer* by invoking `presentDrawable:` and committing the `MTLCommandBuffer`.

Since there are only 3 drawables in the pool, the catch is that you have to manage this lifecycle yourself, by adding appropriate CPU resource synchronization at the time you invoke `nextDrawable` and in the callback you get once rendering is complete (as per the `MTLCommandBuffer addCompletedHandler:` callback set-up).

Typically you use a `dispatch_semaphore_t` for this:

```
_resource_semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(3);
```

then put the following just before you invoke `nextDrawable`:

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(_resource_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

and this in your `addCompletedHandler:` callback handler:

```
dispatch_semaphore_signal(_resource_semaphore);
```

Have a look at some of the simple Metal sample apps from Apple to see this in action. There is not a lot in terms of Apple documentation on this.